# Rails: Custom Model Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

Hi I am trying to write a custom validation for a model that does not allow the model to be saved if it fails the validation.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  validate :valid_est_time

  private

  def valid_est_time
    if !self.est_time.is_a? Integer || self.est_time >= 0
      self.errors.add("Invalid Response Estimated Time.")
    end 
  end
```

The validation works by not saving the model, but it also throws an error (which I dont want it to do)

```
NoMethodError in Jobs#index

Showing /Users/squitorio/Documents/Project/Dispatcher/assist/app/views/jobs/_index_active.html.erb where line #19 raised:

undefined method `minutes' for nil:NilClass
```

I just want it to not save the model, and carry on

Comment: What does your `_index_active.html.erb` look like?

Comment: Looks like your partial is calling `.minutes` on something that's supposed to be a Time but is actually `nil` - probably the `est_time` attribute of this model?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the before_save callback. If you return false from any of the methods called before_save it cancels all the subsequent callbacks. This will stop your model from saving. Have a look at this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

If you still want to use other features of Rails validation then take a look at custom validations here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations